# Axios Cache-Control: max-age=0 still makes the site store cache

Tags: reactjs, caching, http-headers, axios, office-addins

I have an Office Application for Word Addin that is build on top of react. Whenever I do API calls to the database I get an 200 response and I get the data no problems. 
But whenever the database changes and I do a new call, I get 200 / OK, and the old link is saved in cache so I wont get an updated list of numbers.

I've used the code beneath to set Cache-Control to max-age 0, but it still gives the same 200 / OK and it says the old result is in Cache.

In my response header I do get two fields. One called *Cache-Control: max-age=0* , and one called *Authorization: Bearer {token}*. I do have other fields also, but they wont make a difference.

**So my question is this:**

1. How would I solved this in front-end?
2. I've talked to someone who kindof knew this and said that the API also needed to do some handling, if so, how would I do this?

```
const getClient = () => {
  const authToken = window.sessionStorage.getItem('authToken');
  const options = {
    baseURL: getBaseUrl()
  };
  options.headers = {
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
  };
  const client = axios.create(options);

  client.interceptors.request.use(
    requestConfig => requestConfig,
    requestError => {
      // BAD REQUEST
      return Promise.reject(requestError);
    }
  );

  client.interceptors.response.use(
    response => response,
    error => {
      if (error.response.status >= 500) {
        //LOOK INTO SENTRY.IO FOR ERROR MONITORING
      }

      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  return client;
};

export default {
  get(url, conf = {}) {
    return getClient()
      .get(url, conf)
      .then(response => Promise.resolve(response))
      .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
  },

  head(url, conf = {}) {
    return getClient()
      .head(url, conf)
      .then(response => Promise.resolve(response))
      .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
  },

  options(url, conf = {}) {
    return getClient()
      .options(url, conf)
      .then(response => Promise.resolve(response))
      .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
  },
};

const getBaseUrl = () => {
  if (process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENV === 'staging') {
    return s_root;
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    return p_root;
  }
  return d_root;
};
```

Comment: I faced sort of the same problem recently and found that it cannot be solved on the frontend. You need to configure your server in some cases to manage the cache properly.